# Cassandra LWT writes producing incorrect data

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We have a 3-node Cassandra cluster (single DC), and a table that get accessed (for read/writes) by applications running on separate nodes.

Under heavy load, when both instances of the application are attempting to update the same user entry (E.g. add attribute) we observe that update from `app1` (running on `node1` succeeded - i.e. `ResultSet#wasApplied` returns `true`). However, when `app2` (on `node2` reads the data, it is getting stale data before `app1` updated it).

I'd like to know why this is happening because LTW with serial consistency should prevent this type of inconsistencies. Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

**Example:** (based on application logs)

1. Initially the user has attribute `A` with value `1`
2. Both `app1` and `app2` are adding new attributes; `app1` adding `B:2` and `app2` adding `C:3`
3. `app1` read the correct data into memory, added new attribute `B` and wrote to Cassandra successfully. The logs show the final attribute list having `A:1` and `B:2` tuples.
4. `app2` reads the data, but only see `A:1` (the difference in time between the logs from `app1` and `app2` is only 2ms; therefore could have happened in any order).
5. Once `app2`'s write is completed, the end state only has `A:1` and `C:2`, which is incorrect.

**More Information**

The (prepared statements that perform) reads and writes to the table have the following characteristics:

- Write is a LWT (on IF EXISTS userid)
- Writes on the table are performed with a consistency level of LOCAL_QUORUM
- Reads on the table are performed with a consistency level of LOCAL_SERIAL

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(userid ascii, username ascii, attributes map);
```

The logic within the app when updating the attributes map is:

```
User user = dao.getUser(userid);
user.addNewAttribute("key", "value");
dao.update(user);
```

Comment: need to see the code for user.addNewAttribute("key", "value");
could it be that you delete/null the unset fields?

Comment: @Schildmeijer it was a simple `attributes.put(key, value)` where `attributes` is a standard Java HashMap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the read/writes were happening on 2 different nodes, we weren't synchronising the operations at the application level.

`app2` was doing the `read` before `app1` was started the write. Therefore, `app1` got the stale data (not stale data). The `update` operation set the entire map instead of add/removing the elements to/from the map.

We've changed the logic, so the add/remove operations are now doing an add (and remove respectively) instead of doing a "read and then set".

The new prepared statement looks something like:

```
QueryBuilder.update("my_table")
            .onlyIf(QueryBuilder.eq("username", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()))
            .with(QueryBuilder.putAll("attributes", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()))
            .and(QueryBuilder.set("lastUpdatedOn", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()))
            .where(QueryBuilder.eq("userid", QueryBuilder.bindMarker()));
```

Before the attributes were set using `set`